# Remove multiple spaces only between numbers in file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Input file:

```
101|989881|Customer contact 123 456  7777|AXD

102|989882|Declined sales. Details 122 -333 - 1234 contact|XYZ
```

Output file:

```
101|9881|Customer contact 1234567777|AXD

102|9882|Declined sales. Details 
122-333-1234 contact|XYZ
```

Tried:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([0-9]\)/\1\2/g' inputfile
```

This command removes only if one space present between numbers and not satisfy other conditions.

Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there!  The following does what you want...  It deletes multiple consecutive spaces, and also continues until you have no more matches (the purpose of the t command)... this handles the case where you match '0 - 0' -- without the t statement, the second match '- 0' would not be processed because the '-' was in the previous match.

```
sed ':x; s/\([0-9-]\) \+\([0-9-]\)/\1\2/g; tx' inputfile
```

There is one potential weakness... and that is that you may not want to delete spaces when you encounter '- -'.  This would require a bit more work:

```
sed ':x; s/\([0-9]\) \+\([0-9-]\)/\1\2/g; tx; :y; s/\([0-9-]\) \+\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g; ty;' inputfile
```